# Start sshd automatically with docker container

Tags: docker, sshd

Given:

- container based on ubuntu:13.10
- installed ssh (via `apt-get install ssh`)

Problem: each when I start container I have to run sshd manually `service ssh start`

Tried: `update-rc.d ssh defaults`, but it does not helps.

**Question: how to setup container to start sshd service automatically during container start?**

Comment: Temporary solved by adding corresponding line to `/etc/bash.bashrc`. But this is ugly way, IMHO.

Comment: There is IMHO better solution. Check my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27860506/openssh-server-doesnt-start-in-docker-container/62259551#62259551

Answer (score -18, accepted):

You can try a more elegant way to do that with phusion/baseimage-docker

https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#readme

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question posed. It's a side-channel to get a Docker container with `sshd` running, not a way to start `sshd` automatically in a Docker container. Useless for people who can't change the image they inherit from.

Comment: irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 48):

Just try:

```
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && bash
```

in your dockerfile, it works fun for me!

more details here: [How to automatically start a service when running a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135897/how-to-automatically-start-a-service-when-running-a-docker-container/32179054#32179054)

Comment: try it here    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135897/how-to-automatically-start-a-service-when-running-a-docker-container/32179054#32179054

Answer (score 18):

Here is a `Dockerfile` which installs ssh server and runs it:

```
# Build Ubuntu image with base functionality.
FROM ubuntu:focal AS ubuntu-base
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

# Setup the default user.
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/ubuntu -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo ubuntu
RUN echo 'ubuntu:ubuntu' | chpasswd
USER ubuntu
WORKDIR /home/ubuntu

# Build image with Python and SSHD.
FROM ubuntu-base AS ubuntu-with-sshd
USER root

# Install required tools.
RUN apt-get -qq update \
    && apt-get -qq --no-install-recommends install vim-tiny=2:8.1.* \
    && apt-get -qq --no-install-recommends install sudo=1.8.* \
    && apt-get -qq --no-install-recommends install python3-pip=20.0.* \
    && apt-get -qq --no-install-recommends install openssh-server=1:8.* \
    && apt-get -qq clean    \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure SSHD.
# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN bash -c 'install -m755 <(printf "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0") /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d'
RUN ex +'%s/^#\zeListenAddress/\1/g' -scwq /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN ex +'%s/^#\zeHostKey .*ssh_host_.*_key/\1/g' -scwq /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN RUNLEVEL=1 dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
RUN ssh-keygen -A -v
RUN update-rc.d ssh defaults

# Configure sudo.
RUN ex +"%s/^%sudo.*$/%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL/g" -scwq! /etc/sudoers

# Generate and configure user keys.
USER ubuntu
RUN ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#COPY --chown=ubuntu:root "./files/authorized_keys" /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Setup default command and/or parameters.
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/bin/sudo", "/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-o", "ListenAddress=0.0.0.0"]
```

Build with the following command:

```
docker build --target ubuntu-with-sshd -t ubuntu-with-sshd .
```

Then run with:

```
docker run -p 2222:22 ubuntu-with-sshd
```

To connect to container via local port, run: `ssh -v localhost -p 2222`.

To check for container IP address, use `docker ps` and `docker inspect`.

---

Here is example of `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
---
version: '3.4'
services:
  ubuntu-with-sshd:
    image: "ubuntu-with-sshd:latest"
    build:
      context: "."
      target: "ubuntu-with-sshd"
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.16.128.2
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
    privileged: true # Required for /usr/sbin/init
networks:
  mynet:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.128.0/24
```

To run, type:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Comment: Why do you need EXPOSE and a port mapping to 2222? I read that you only need that if you want to provide access to the container from outside the host

Comment: EXPOSE is purely documental. It does not automatically exposes ports. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose
You need to expose the port to access it from the host.

Comment: To make this work I had to remove the in docker ssh-keygen -t ed25519 line, uncommend the next copy authorized keys line, and then generate the keys outside of the docker image so I could login with: `ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ./files/id_ed25519 -F none -v ubuntu@localhost -p 2222`

Answer (score 13):

I think the correct way to do it would follow docker's instructions to dockerizing the ssh service.

And in correlation to the specific question, the following lines added at the end of the dockerfile will achieve what you were looking for:

```
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

[Dockerize a SSHD service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/)

Comment: doesn't work: when I `attach` to the running Docker, there's no ssh server running.

Comment: please can you clearify what `-D` for?

Comment: -D = When this option is specified, sshd will not detach and does not become a daemon. You can execute "man sshd" to learn that.

Comment: Link no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

I have created dockerfiler to run ssh inside. **I think it is not secure, but for testing/development in DMZ it could be ok**:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

USER root

# change root password to `ubuntu`
RUN echo 'root:ubuntu' | chpasswd

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# install ssh server
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  openssh-server sudo \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# workdir for ssh
RUN mkdir -p /run/sshd

# generate server keys
RUN ssh-keygen -A

# allow root to login
RUN sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

EXPOSE 22

# run ssh server
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "-o", "ListenAddress=0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: As an extension of this docker, you may want to copy pregenerated priv/pub keys and disable password login, and/or add non-root user.

Answer (score 2):

You can start ssh server when starting your container probably. Something like this:

```
docker run ubuntu /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Check out this [official tutorial](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/examples/running_ssh_service/).

Comment: It will start a new container. how to start a pre-existing container, and auto-start sshd?

Comment: Now you can start sshd with docker exec - https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#exec

Comment: broken link i think

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did:

```
FROM nginx

# install gosu
# seealso:
# https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/
# https://github.com/tianon/gosu/blob/master/INSTALL.md
# https://github.com/tianon/gosu
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y gosu; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
# verify that the binary works
    gosu nobody true

ENV myenv='default'

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/usr/local/airflow
RUN mkdir $AIRFLOW_HOME
RUN groupadd --gid 8080 airflow
RUN useradd --uid 8080 --gid 8080 -ms /bin/bash -d $AIRFLOW_HOME airflow
RUN echo 'airflow:mypass' | chpasswd


EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Inside entrypoint.sh:

```
echo "starting ssh as root"
gosu root service ssh start &
#gosu root /usr/sbin/sshd -D &

echo "starting tail user"
exec gosu airflow tail -f /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I used the following command to solve that

```
docker run -i -t  mycentos6 /bin/bash -c '/etc/init.d/sshd start && /bin/bash'
```

Answer (score -1):

First login to your container and write an initialization script `/bin/init` as following:

```sh
# execute in the container
cat <<EOT >> /bin/init
#!/bin/bash
service ssh start
while true; do sleep 1; done
EOT
```

Then make the `root` user is permitted to logging via ssh:

```sh
# execute in the container
echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Commit the container to a new image after exiting from the container:

```sh
# execute in the server
docker commit <YOUR_CONTAINER> <ANY_REPO>:<ANY_TAG>
```

From now on, as long as you run your container with the following command, the ssh service will be automatically started.

```sh
# execute in the server
docker run -it -d --name <NAME> <REPO>:<TAG> /bin/init
docker exec -it <NAME> /bin/bash
```

Done.

Comment: You should almost never use `docker commit`.  Instead, write the commands to set up the image in a Dockerfile (and check it into source control), as the other answers to this question do.