# Multiple independent mariadb usages: multiple containers or one? Isolation vs efficiency?

Tags: docker, database-design, architecture, mariadb

I have an architectural question.

Suppose we have a system that has multiple sub-systems: `A`, `B`, and so on.  Each of these sub-system needs to persist their data and they all use `MariaDB`.  Sub-system `A` may need a `database` (as in `create database ...`) called `a_db`; and Sub-system `B` may need a database called `b_db`.  Furthermore, there are no data sharing across `A` and `B`

In a monolithic world before microservice and docker, it is common to set up one central `MariaDB` instance and ask each sub-system to use it and to *just use your own* `database` while on the shared instance (That is, `A` uses `a_db`, `B` uses `b_db`, and so on)

With docker, I think we could also have multiple mariadb containers running, and each maps their own volume for storage (e.g. `/data/mdb_a` and `/data/mdb_b`, respectively).

An obvious advantage would be complete isolation between `A` and `B`.  There would be no worries that `A` may accidentally mess with `B`'s data.  And the two sub-systems can independently choose to shutdown/restart their own MariaDB container or even upgrade their MariaDB binary.

On the other hand, some of my colleagues argue that running multiple MariaDB containers is inefficient and this approach imposes waste of resources.

Are their good empirical measurements and articles discuss the trade-offs between the two approaches?

Comment: As you say, there are tradeoffs.  Is "isolation" more important than "efficiency".  You don't yet know if the app will come anywhere close to using up the horsepower of the server.

Comment: I had this debate once with a colleague and we came up with a metric to decide when to containerise a database and it was simple, we weigh the number of total database issues per app vs how many times those crashes affected other apps. We get the percentage and if it was more than 30% we'd isolate the offending app, which would increase the stability of the other systems by that much. I'll try to come up with an answer that explains our final solution to this. We ended up containerising everything in the end but we had to treat database containers in a special
 way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistent storage in the containerized world is still in its infancy, and can be problematic in high traffic environments when running more than one replica of your database(in this case, mariadb).

Running more than one mariadb replica, with shared persistent data storage(e.g. NFS), regardless of the number of databases you use, could cause some corruption issues.

I have not experienced these things myself, but you should research running databases in containers further, before doing anything in production. There are lots of articles on the web about this.

A lot of people still run their databases in VM's, or on bare metal, and only run databases in containers for local development only.