# docker-compose.yml + ssh-server not working

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to start my docker-compose.yml (example below), but whenever I start the containers the sshd server service not working:

```
# My docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  server1:
    image: server-dev:v0.8
    hostname: server-dev1
    command: bash -c "/usr/sbin/init"
    ports:
      - "2222:22"
      - 80:80
  server2:
    image: server-dev:v0.8
    hostname: server-dev2
    command: bash -c "/usr/sbin/init"
    depends_on:
      - server1
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about what exactly is not working? Do you have any log output, relevant parts of your Dockerfiles of your images (CMD/ENTRYPOINT)? As a starting point for a self-made ssh container, maybe this official docker example can be helpful: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

Comment: #My Dockerfile
FROM centos
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]

Comment: ## My Dockerfile part2
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]

ENV container=docker

EXPOSE 53/udp 22 53 80 443 389 636 88 464 88/udp 464/udp 123/udp 7389 9443 9444 9445

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/info/
COPY usr/share/info/*.gz /usr/share/info/

RUN yum -y install epel-release; \
    yum -y update; \
    yum -y install bind-utils vim openssh-server openssh-clients; \
    yum -y install ipa-server; \
    systemctl enable dnsmasq; \
    yum -y install ipa-server-dns bindipa-server  bind-dyndb-ldap; \
    yum clean all

CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Comment: Related: [Start sshd automatically with docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22886470/55075)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building an image from your Dockerfile and running it with

```
docker run -p 2222:22 dschuldt/test
```

throws:

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
```

You can add this line to you dockerfile before the last `CMD` command to make it work (by the way, you have two CMD commands... the first one will be overwritten):

```
RUN /usr/bin/ssh-keygen -A
```

Just another small hint: Your Image is 739MB. Maybe you should rethink your use case ;-)

Have a nice evening, regards

dschuldt

Comment: It's working now.Thanks your support but in relation to your tip. I'm new user to docker, I'm studying ;-)