# dockerfile ssh zombie process for ssh autostart

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile, zombie-process

Hi I have some huge problems with autostart sshd with container.

My dockerfile:
[Dockerfile](https://pastebin.com/JkfQn6Vy)

My entrypoint:
[entrypoint](https://pastebin.com/aXTbV3Bq)

When I enter in to container bash, and type:

> service ssh status

```
[FAIL] sshd is not running ... failed!
```

also I get zombie ssh process :-|

> ps -ef | grep ssh

```
node        15     1  0 14:49 ?        00:00:00 [sshd] defunct

node       183   142  0 14:59 pts/0    00:00:00 grep ssh
```

Did I make some mistakes in the dockerfile ??

Comment: Can you include the Dockerfile, as text, in the question itself, not behind a link?

Comment: oh come on ;) that's just pastebin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use `USER node` at the end of Dockerfile to start sshd, which I guess you want to use `node user` to start `npm`.

But, the suggested way is to use `root` to start sshd & use `node` to start `npm`, you can see a famous project `redis` which use same solution [here](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/916d3d22527edd7461738396431fb237d39d0b3a/5.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L13)

Then, you needed to next fix:

1. Delete `USER node` at the end of Dockerfile before `CMD`.
2. Delete `RUN chmod 0444 /etc/ssh/*` in your dockerfile

   Otherwise, it will reported next which make sshd not work:

   > Permissions 0444 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key' are too open.
3. Delete `RUN echo 'PermitRootLogin=without-password' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, use next to replace:

   ```
   RUN echo 'PermitRootLogin=yes' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
4. Add `RUN apt-get install -y gosu` in Dockerfile to install gosu which will later be used in `entrypoint.sh`
5. In `entrypoint.sh`, change `exec "$@"` to next:

   ```
   exec gosu node "$@"
   ```

   This will assure `npm start` still run with user node.

Then, you can see when start the container, the sshd works, you can use `service ssh stop && service ssh start` to restart the service if you needed, but as the container run sshd well now, I guess you no need to use this again.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your entrypoint script.

```
service ssh restart && bash
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178958/6790948).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with:
```service ssh restart && bash```