# Start SSH daemon in Laravel sail

Tags: laravel, docker, dockerfile, openssh, laravel-sail

I'm using Laravel Sail and have published the `Dockerfile` (so I can edit it manually). The reason being that I need to use an OpenSSH server on the container itself for a program I'm using.

I am able to install OpenSSH by adding `&& apt-get install -y openssh-server` to the packages section and configure it with the following:

```
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd
EXPOSE 22
```

The issue though is that it does not start when the container starts.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178958/11490328) you can add an `ENTRYPOINT` as follows:

```
ENTRYPOINT service ssh restart && bash
```

However you can only have one `ENTRYPOINT` and Laravel Sail has this by default:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

I have tried the following:

- add `/usr/sbin/sshd` to the `start-container` script - *it didn't start*
- add `CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]` into the `Dockerfile` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59845307/11490328) - *it gave a permission denied error when starting the container*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the php container uses [supervisor](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/start-container#L16) you can add another application to the [config](https://github.com/laravel/sail/blob/1.x/runtimes/8.1/supervisord.conf). Reference for the config can be found [here](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html).

**Example**

```
ssh.ini:
[program:sshd]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Comment: Will this require me to rebuild the container?

Comment: @MatthewKnill  I would do it to be sure, but I suspect not.

Comment: Yep after I did the rebuild it worked